# How to draw a square inside the outside of the last circle in android drawable xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, path

I want to draw xml an image like the red image below, someone has tried this, Please help me

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3bnM.png)

Answer (score 0):

you must use `<layer-list>` with two rectangle item and one oval item